# Don't understand the number of levels of "Flatten"

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data

```
data={{{-(1/2), -(3/2)}, {1/2, -(1/2)}, {3/2, 1/
   2}}, {{-(3/2), -(5/2)}, {-(1/2), -(3/2)}, {1/2, -(1/2)}, {3/2, 1/
   2}, {5/2, 3/2}}}
```

I want to change this data to this
[image]

Inorder solve this ploblem I can use

```
TreeForm@data
```

get this

[image]

By looking at the data, I found that the second part lsit should be deleted
[image]

I want to get rid of all the parentheses here

[image]

I tried a lot of things to no avail, so I finally asked "chatgpt"

```mathematica
Flatten[data, {{1}, {2, 3}}]
```

[image]

The problem is solved, but I don't understand how to use the "layer number" in Flatten, I'm confused

Comment: `Flatten` left layer (aka level) 1 alone and flattened layers 2 and 3. (You have layer 3 outlined in the red box. Everything below it was put into layer two, divided according to layer 2.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 As you can see, the list of the third layer connects the data, why not flatten the third layer?, I don't understand

Comment: In my view, the third layer was flattened. What do you mean - that is, what did you expect the output to be?

Comment: @MichaelE2 How to understant levels of "Flatten" function?

Comment: The flatten code says leave level 1 alone and flatten each item in level with its contents down to level 3.  The hard one to describe is when the levels are transposed, such as in `Flatten[data, {{1, 3}, {2}}]`, which might be the code you desire.

Comment: Maybe mapping Transpose and then Flatten a level?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The correct solution ”chatgpt“ as well solved, I am now confused

Comment: @xzczd I've seen this post before, but I don't understand it. I really don't understand the Flatten function

Comment: Also, since you can read Chinese, check this: https://tieba.baidu.com/p/2597584262

Comment: It's the best post about 2nd argument of `Flatten` in this site. If you still feel confused, please clarify which part you're having difficulty.

Comment: @xzczd What's a more straightforward way to understand this function

Comment: @xzczd It is described in the help document as "layer", here it is more difficult to understand with corner notation

Comment: I don't think there exists a "more straightforward way". What you're expecting is just like, "I want to set an `Assumptions` option to integral, but I still want to use the pretty 2D `∫`. " <- This is just impossible, to set `Assumptions` you have to use the 1D `Integrate[…]`

Comment: Also, notice that when explaining 2nd argument of `Flatten`, the document states: Flatten[list, {{$s_{11}$, $s_{12}$, …}, {$s_{21}$, $s_{22}$, …}, …}] flattens list by combining all levels $\color{red}{s_{ij}}$ to make each level $i$ in the result. It uses "corner notation", too.